# Ansible orchestration for ufw with ufw --force enable

Tags: debian, firewall, ansible, ufw

I deploy an Ansible playbook to some `debian:stable` machines aiming to update package index cache, install `ufw` and setup it in the Ansible architecture-agnostic and version-agnostic way.

```
- name: Update all apt package index cache (apt update)
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install a latest ufw
  apt:
    name: ufw
    state: latest

- name: Setup firewall with ufw
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: 22,25,80,443
```

**My difficulty here**

In Bash I also regularly use `ufw --force enable` but I didn't find how to add it to the playbook in Ansible-YAML syntax in [Ansible ufw documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/ufw_module.html).

**My question**

How should I add `ufw --force enable` correctly, if at all?

Comment: Are you suggesting that it gets installed but stays disabled?

Comment: @tink Hi ! Well, no, I just want to understand why the docs doesn't mention these arguments of `--force` and `enable`.

Comment: There's `state = enabled/disabled`... I don't think using `--force` is idempotent, which is the one of the idea behind using Ansible

Comment: @cricket_007 AFAIK an indempotent function is a function that works but gets us nowhere. I didn't learn enough math in my youth and being hard to ensure I understand what **idempotent** means. Did you mean to say "given `state=enabled/disabled` is there, using `--force` is idempotent?

Comment: It means that when re-ran, the state remains the same. For example, when copying files, it'll compare checksums, or deleting files, it first checks the file isn't there to begin with. By adding a `force` operation, you are explicitly saying "always run this action", which is somewhat against Ansible etiquette

Comment: FWIW, maybe asking on Github would be better? But the source code is here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/ufw.py#L314-L339

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I understand now --- because `--force` declares "non interactive usage" and Ansible already decleares it by itself, using `--force` in ansible will lead us no where.

Comment: @cricket_007 if I understood you right, please publish a small answer (mostly copy-pasting these data) and I'll gladly accept and upvote.

Comment: Well, I haven't acually *used* the Ansible ufw module, and when looking at that code, I do see a `-f` flag... However, not sure if that is the short form of `--force`, or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to run shell commands, you use the Ansible `shell` or `command` modules.

As far as `ufw` goes, I think it directly edits the rules files. Looking at the source code, it's running this, before and after the actions to check if these files have changed contents.

```
grep '^### tuple' /lib/ufw/user.rules /lib/ufw/user6.rules /etc/ufw/user.rules /etc/ufw/user6.rules
```

As far as enabling, or disabling, that is what the `state` action is for

If you say `state: enabled`, it'll do `ufw -f enable`

```
    if command == 'state':
        states = {'enabled': 'enable', 'disabled': 'disable',
                  'reloaded': 'reload', 'reset': 'reset'}
        execute(cmd + [['-f'], [states[value]]])
```

Comment: Strange, `man ufw` doesn't even mention `-f` argument hence shows no evidence that `-f` and `--force` are the same.

Comment: I noticed the same. I imagine they are, given that it seems to be used the same way